# Qt / How can I have subwindows without losing the main window focus?

Tags: qt, dialog

I have a main window (on MS Windows) and I want to have sub windows or subpanels with free screen movement. I can use dialog and `Qt::splashscreen` flag, but when I am on these subwindows I lose the focus caption for the main window. Is there any trick to do what I want? (Something like a multi-focus...)
Maybe it is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by losing the focus.

When I create an application with multiple windows, this is what I do: in the sub-window widget, I set the parent to the main window, and set the Qt::Tool flag. It has multiple effects: the window manager sees it as one window, and when you focus any window, all the windows raise.

Comment: MDI approach is not what I want, unless in this case I could to have the sub-windows outside the mdi-main-window. I think that what I have to do is to create a main window without title caption, writing the right code to simulate receive and lost focus. In example, the apps I see that works in this direction use this way, in example dreamweaver and maybe autocad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmdiarea.html)? Or a [focus proxy](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy)?

In Qt, all top-level windows are independent, none is the "main". If you want to nominate one as a main window and have it steal focus from the others, then you will have to [implement that manually](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setFocus).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to have widgets that you can move around freely on a parent widget/window, without invoking the "window focus changed" event between native Windows windows (...).

I'm not sure if there is a ready-made solution for that, but adding some grab/move/resize events to a widget's edges shouldn't be *that* hard, or?

I'd simply catch mousedown/up events on certain areas (these should probably be widgets of their own with a link to the parent movable widget), and have them resize/move the window when the mouse moves.